# Autofilter write in coding is not function like recorded in macro

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill, autofilter, vba

I face a problem here.

```
formula = "=CONCATENATE(""ML"",MID(cell(C),2,1),MID(cell(C),4,5),""M"",RIGHT(cell(C),2),""_"",LEFT(D52,1),""_Q"")"

ActiveSheet.Range("$H$2:$H$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="=SAMP"
'exclude the header  
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = formula
'Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Selection.FillDown
```

I trying to filter my column H with this coding. After filter, I want to fill down those cells with formula. Is that any problem on my formula there, it can execute, but doesn't work like what I expected. And this codes although is same like the macros. but when run it, the data rows show not same like what I used macro recorded.

Comment: try to change this line: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = formula` into `ActiveCell.Formula = formula`. And I hope `formula` works ok as a string- I didn't check it...

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `.FormulaR1C1` property, which expects formulas to use R1C1 notation, while the string is written in normal A1 notation, so you should be setting the `.Formula` property.